# JazzCash Wallet Integration (V4 - Recurring Payments)

Tags: node.js, payment, ibm-jazz

Here is the documentation of JazzCash Recurring payment [https://sandbox.jazzcash.com.pk/SandboxDocumentation/v4.2/ApiReferences.html#wa](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).

I have checked the document in detail but there is no URL provided for any api in documentation. Anyone please help in this case.

HERE are my findings till now. Wallet association API is giving 404 response code
[image]

I need a valid URL to call Jazzcash wallet Association/Integration API. You can check above screenshot api response has 404 code error.

Anyone please help to find a solution for it.

Comment: Hi Folks, I find this out, Here is the implementation of JazzCash wallet integration please refer to this GitHub repository https://github.com/shehryar96/Jazzcash-mobile-wallet-Integration